# macOS - Selecting and deleting non-duplicate filenames with different extensions

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I work as a night-time photographer. Every night I collect about 800 RAW files + 800 JPG files. I skim my pictures selecting JPG files, that is to say I delete all the pictures I don't want, then I mark my JPG files with a grey tag and I transfer them into RAW files folder.

In the final phase I have my original 800 RAW files + more or less 200 JPG tagged files in the same folder. I now have 200 JPG files matching exactly 200 of the 800 RAW-file names.

I sort all my files in this folder by name and eventually I manually delete all the non duplicate files. The grey tags help me during this process: I leave each JPG file (with a grey tag) and its correspondent/matching RAW file (with the same name as the `.JPG` but with a `.NEF` extension) being right below the JPG.

The screenshot at the bottom of this post shows this final phase.

How can I automate this part of my work flow? Is there a simple script I could run?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm with you on the irritation factor of Nikon saving RAW+JPG as two files rather than one - but is it really that vital that you have both? What are you doing your initial 'contact sheet' culling in? I ended up just using ViewNX-i from NEFs only, save TIFs of my keepers, work up in Ps, then discard the intermediate TIFs [as the NEF+NKSC is smaller to keep long-term. Wish I could help on your automation idea, but I can't think of any simple way to tackle the problem.

Comment: Which part of the flow do you want to automate? Just the removal of any RAWs where there is no JPG any more, the removal of both RAW *and* JPG if the JPG is either missing or not tagged "grey", or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can automate the last step using *Terminal*.

You can see all `.NEF` files in a directory by using *find*.  For example from within the directory.

```
find  *.NEF -type f
```

Then for each NEF check if corresponding JPG *doesn't* exist by using *basename* to remove the `.NEF` extension and then replace it with `.JPG`.  This will print NEF files without a matching JPG.

```
find  *.NEF -type f -exec sh -c 'for f do [ ! -f $(basename $f .NEF).JPG ] && echo $f unmatched; done' find-sh {} \;
```

If that looks OK then replace `echo $f unmatched` with `rm $f` to delete the file rather than print the name.

```
find  *.NEF -type f -exec sh -c 'for f do [ ! -f $(basename $f .NEF).JPG ] && rm $f; done' find-sh {} \;
```

**For example:**

```bsh
A1398% ls
1.NEF   2.JPG   2.NEF   3.NEF   4.JPG   4.NEF   5.NEF
A1398% find  *.NEF -type f -exec sh -c 'for f do [ ! -f $(basename $f .NEF).JPG ] && rm $f; done' find-sh {} \;
A1398% ls
2.JPG   2.NEF   4.JPG   4.NEF
```